# MacOS security update mechanism

Tags: security

Ubuntu has a command line mechanism for security updates:

```
sudo apt update
```

Does MacOS have a similar command line mechanism to provide updates without a release?

Update:
The scope is limited to the the operating system and I would like to understand what options are available the user has to task an update check & install. I am not aware of any pull that can be triggered from the command line. I am aware (and use) the home-brew package manager, however, I doubt it is intended for this purpose. I do keep Catalina up to date with Apple releases.

Answer (score 4):

## `softwareupdate`

> Software Update checks for new and updated versions of your software based on information about your computer and current software.

See `softwareupdate -h` and `man softwareupdate` for the equivalent functionality on macOS.

To install the recommended updates, issue the command:

```
sudo softwareupdate --install --recommended
```

Comment: Note: `softwareupdate` doesn't automatically restart after updates that require it. Run `softwareupdate --list` first, and see which ones list `[restart]` to know if you'll need to restart after installing them.